# Problems with some classes not exporting when it should have arose when porting codebase from Webpack to Rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, porting, rollupjs

So, I'm porting an old 2017 codebase from Webpack to Rollup for performance and code size reasons, also because of the old dependencies that the codebase used.

Unfortunately, The new Rollup version has a problem that I couldn't figure out a solution for. It doesn't seem to export some classes (In this case `Engine` and `BackgroundLayer`), but the Webpack unaltered version does. Is there a reason for this?

The `Error` in question:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Engine is not defined
```

Here's my `rollup.config.js`

```js
import arraybuffer from '@wemap/rollup-plugin-arraybuffer';
import { babel } from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import pkg from './package.json';
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
// import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

export default {
    input: "src/index.js",
    output: {
      name: "index",
      file: `dist/${pkg.name}.js`,
      format: "umd",
    },
    external: ['ms'],
    plugins: [
      arraybuffer({ include: '**/*.dat' }), // so Rollup can import .dat files
      resolve(), // so Rollup can find `ms`
      commonjs(), // so Rollup can convert `ms` to an ES module
      // terser(), // minifying
      // babel configuration
      babel({ exclude: 'node_modules/**', babelHelpers: "runtime", skipPreflightCheck: true }),
    ]
}
```

If anybody requires the full codebase, here are the two versions:

- Webpack Code: https://github.com/kdex/earthbound-battle-backgrounds
- Rollup Code: https://github.com/IamRifki/earthbound-battle-backgrounds-rollup

Comment: I think Rollup is tree shaking your functions as they are not used in your code base, only exported through your index.js.

Comment: Seems like Treeshaking might not be the problem. Tried using `treeshake: false` in `rollup.config.js` and it still doesn't export the necessary classes. I've also tried Rich Harris' own answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787251/10916748), but it doesn't work with or without `treeshake: false`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had to call my `bundle.js` inside a `module`:

`index.html`

```html
<script type="module">
  import { BackgroundLayer, Engine } from "./bundle.js";

  const engine = new Engine([new BackgroundLayer(153), new BackgroundLayer(298)]);
  engine.animate();
</script>
```