# Rollup - keep individual exports from tree-shaking

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I am building a components library which is pre-compiled using [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#tree-shaking).

My components lib has hundreds of files, at random depths, and I need all files with specific name pattern (`*.constants.js`) to not be tree-shaken (legacy backward-compatibility with another project which consumes the one I am working on)

[Simplified example of my code](https://rollupjs.org/repl/?version=2.70.1&shareable=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)

#### `main.js` (entry file)

```js
import { A } from 'foo';
console.log(A)
```

#### `foo.js`

```js
export const A = 1;
export const B = 1;
export const C = 1;
```

#### Rollup output `/build/foo.js`

```
const A = 1;

export { A };
```

A **very important** thing for me is to keep the ability of other codebases (which are using "my" components lib) to be able to import specific things from specific files, such as the above `foo.js` example

**Question** - 
 How do I keep the *exports* from being tree-shaken out of the output (only for `*.constants.js` in my real scenario)?

---

##### Rollup setup:

```js
{
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'build',
    format: 'es', // imperative
    chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
    entryFileNames: '[name].js',
    preserveModules: true,  // imperative
    preserveModulesRoot: 'src',  // imperative
    sourcemap: true,
    exports: 'named',
  }
}
```

Comment: Related but unhelpful - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45785357/104380

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something ugly, but minimal, by tricking rollup to treat tree-shaken variables as if they are used, but dumping them on the global `this` variable, under a random namespace:

For the code example in the question, where only `A` is really used internally by my components, lib, if I want to keep the exports for `B` & `C` I do:

```js
globalThis.__rollup_no_tree_shaking = {B, C};
```